# Using Node, Express, (and Socket.io?) to update a page every 1 second

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am a bit new to Node.js and Express, and am currently working on a page where I would like to generate and send messages (from the server) to the client page every 1 second (1250ms, actually). When a user visits the site, I would like the latest message to be broadcasted, with new messages coming in every second after. In other words, every user would see the same message at the same time on the web page, regardless of when they connected to the server.

I have done some searching and have unfortunately have not had any luck playing with code samples online. Here is a ROUGH IDEA to explain:

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require( "http" ).createServer( app );
var io = require( "socket.io" )( http );


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});


http.listen(3000, function(){
    /* someFunction to generate new LATESTMESSAGE every 1s */

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
      socket.emit('news', { messages: LATESTEMESSAGE })
    });
});
```

I assume I would need to send the message via socket.io from the function that generates the LATESTMESSAGE (every 1s when message is generated, send via socket?)? If that is the case, I am unfamiliar with how I would require socket.io in a page that is NOT the app.js (this function would probably be a class, in its own js file), as socket.io requires app and express (see code above).

I appreciate the help! I have spent a good amount of time pondering this today and would appreciate any direction or assistance. Please let me know if I have not supplied enough information.

p.s. the code above definitely would not accomplish what is needed. just a rough outline to show what i am attempting to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing looks like half-duplex communication i.e. Only the *server* sends data to the client, and not the other way around. Socket.io is full duplex communication, i.e. Server *and* client send data to each other. So technically what would be best for your requirements is Server Sent Events (SSE) using EventStream. Socket.io might be slightly excessive.

Having said that, what you want is to write a Middleware, to which you pass the application. Please take a look at https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Basically, your `io` would be passed in to the middleware functions, so they'd have access to Socket. And the middleware functions in turn would be imported into your `app.js`.